# How to get a single output file with N lines from N multiline files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am looking for some effective way to concatenate multiple multiline files into one file - here is an example for three input files:

**1.txt**:

```
a b
c d
```

**2.txt**:

```
e f
g 
h
```

**3.txt**:

```
ijklmn
```

**output.txt**:

```
a b c d
e f g h 
ijklmn
```

(Replacing each linebreak with single whitespace). Which way can you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using BASH for loop:

```
for i in [0-9]*.txt; do tr '\n' ' ' < "$i"; echo; done > output.txt

cat output.txt
a b c d
e f g h
ijklmn
```

If you want to strip one ending space before each line break then use:

```
for i in [0-9]*.txt; do tr '\n' ' ' < "$i"; echo; done | sed 's/ *$//' > output.txt
```